# What is the maximum distance a spark can jump?

Tags: electricity

Is there a maximum distance a spark can arc across, and if so, what is it and why?

Answer (score 1):

This have to depends how strong the electric field is given. You may refer how spark works here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_spark  . As distance increase, the dielectric breakdown strength also increases exponentially. If you have learnt some basic electronics, you can think of it like this, the resistance of air increase exponentially with the increase of distance. Thus stronger voltage is needed to apply if the current wants to pass through the resistance. One of the largest electric sparks we can commanly see are thunder bolts.

Comment: But you're saying that in principle, there isn't a limit?

Comment: Not to mention things like black holes etc. There are always limits in our universe where you cannot exceed a certain energy level or else our spacetime would breakdown etc. For eg. you cannot travel beyond light speed. So technically speaking, there are still limit to it, but i believe it involves highly sophisticated and complex equations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a lightning bolt is a cloud-to-ground spark, so if there's maximum spark-gap distance it's comparable to or larger than the height of Earth's atmosphere.  There is [lightning on larger planets as well](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2007/10/071009-jupiter-lightning.html), whose bolts could be longer because the atmosphere is larger.  A sufficiently large planet would become hot enough to have an ionized/conducting atmosphere, so there isn't lightning on, say, the Sun.  (Solar flares are magnetic, rather than electric, phenomena.)

An [electric spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_spark)
occurs when the electric field in a
[dielectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric)
--- that is, a
[polarizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability) medium ---
becomes strong enough to separate the positive from the negative charges; the free charges are then available to flow as a current along the direction of the field.
All insulating materials are dielectric to some extent, because the [vacuum is polarizable as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization): a sufficiently strong static electric field can, in principle, induce [field emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission) of electron-positron pairs.
The scale of this maximum physical electric field is when the potential energy of an electron or positron in the field changes by an electron's rest energy over an electron's Compton wavelength,
$$
E_\text{f.e.} \sim \frac{m_ec^2}{q_e \lambda_e} \sim \frac{\rm 500\,kV}{\rm 2\,pm}.
$$
I believe that a static electric field strong enough for vacuum field emission has never been produced in a laboratory, but if it's physically allowed then it occurs in nature somewhere.

A device for producing a longest-possible spark would, therefore, maintain something close to this maximum physical field over some macroscopic distance.  If the distances involved become astronomical, then it would no longer become possible to construct [parallel plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Parallel-plate_model) with a relatively uniform field volume, so it'd be better to consider the interaction between two highly-charged spheres.  However at these field strengths [it becomes necessary to consider the gravitational self-interaction of the electric field](https://what-if.xkcd.com/140/), and the well-motivated conjecture that Nature forbids naked singularities suggests that there's a maximum charge density that can be achieved in any region of space just like there's a maximum mass density.

So, build two maximally-charged black holes and let them approach each other.  Among the many interesting things that will happen afterwards is the universe's longest spark.